# How to protect wheelbarrow from rust while still working on it

Tags: repair, outdoor, metal

TLDR: How do I protect metal projects from rusting when they take more than a day to finish?

I’m restoring our old wheelbarrow. Stripping all the metal parts clean, filling holes, primer, paint, top coat, replacing all wood & fastening parts, the works. My problem is I’m a night owl that lives in the city, so I haven’t been able to work on it until after 6-7ish pm and constantly getting interrupted/having to stop working on it, plus working outside as my only option currently, I usually stop any loud work by 8:30-9ish.

I put it under my walled-in pop up canopy that serves as my workshop, and when I get back to work on it, it’s got surface rust. Wash and repeat…how can I temporarily protect it so I can actually finish getting it to clean metal and get it painted?

I have a handful of other metal projects I’m planning on doing once this one’s finished, and I know I’m going to run into the same problem.

Comment: Primer sounds well suited to the task. Many would prime over the rust. Is this an auto quality paint finish or something? A very light spraying of "cold galvanizing" primer might sand nicely with the zinc inhibiting any surface rust, but I'm speculating. Obviously you could use some kind of oil and degrease as part of your paint prep.

Comment: I’m gonna be priming then painting, but I can’t get to that part bc I keep having to sand off the surface rust, and end up having to stop working before I can finish that part. I’m trying to prevent the surface rust from re-forming in between work sessions. You said use some kind of oil? What kind? Degreasing’s def faster & easier than removing  the rust!

Comment: Is the surface rust a problem because of its texture. Because painting over minimal surface rust isn't a problem. Cold galvanizing primer. That's the stuff you would use.

Comment: After cleaning an area of surface rust I've had good results using a zinc-phosphate metal prep product to prevent further rust forming. Note that this is not just phosphoric acid rust converter and metal etcher, but a product which leaves a zinc coating on the metal.

Comment: I just want to be able to prime & paint it from clean metal. Yes, I know I’m being a picky perfectionist. But as I said, this isn’t the only metal project I have on my list, and many of the other ones it actually needs to be clean metal. I just don’t know how I can temporarily protect metal in between work sessions. Like, would spraying a coat of just WD-40 work? Brushing on a coat of 3-in-1? Some other type of oil?

Comment: Work in sections, prep : clean then prime allow to dry or protect and work on a different section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an ideal use for a water displacement product. If any of the first 39 formulations had worked better, we wouldn't know it as WD-40™. This is. literally. the *exact* [reason](https://www.wd40.com/history/) the product was created.

Clean & prep a part. Dose it in WD-40. Set it aside. When you're ready to paint, degrease a part(s) & paint.

Other products may work just as well. *I'm not an employee or shareholder of WD-40. No endorsement or recommendation intended or implied.*

Just don't use it as a lubricant - it's really not all that good at that. Additionally, while it does work to loosen stuck parts, there are *far* more effective products available on the market.

Answer (score 0):

Prime each section when you get it clean. Don't fuss about priming the whole thing at once, that's not needed (or steel ships would never be painted at all...)

Then clean up and prime another section. When it's all primed, you can sand to blend any distressing lap marks and shoot another coat of primer over it all, then paint the whole thing.